# Single Cypher query to choose between 2 different paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following scenario:
At some point in my path (in a node that lies a few links away from my start node),
I have the possibility of going down one path or another, for example:
If S is my startnode,

```
S-[]->..->(B)-[first:FIRST_WAY]->(...) ,
```

and

```
S-[]->..->(B)-[second:SECOND_WAY]->(...)
```

At the junction point, I will need to go down one path only (*first* or *second*)
Ideally, I would like to follow and include results from the *second* relationship, **only if** the *first* one is not present (regardless of what exists afterwards).
Is this possible with Cypher 1.9.7, in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to an optional match to match the patterns separately. Example:

```
MATCH (n:Object) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r1:FIRST_WAY]->(:Object)-->(f1:Object) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r2:SECOND_WAY]->()-->(f2:Object) RETURN coalesce(f2, f1)
```

This query will match both conditionally and the `coalesce` function will return the first result which is not null.

AFAIK, `OPTIONAL_MATCH` was introduced in 2.0 so you can't use that clause in 1.9, but there is an alternate syntax:

```
CYPHER 1.9 START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r1?:FIRST_WAY]->()-->(f1), (n)-[r2?:SECOND_WAY]->()-->(f2) RETURN coalesce(f2, f1)
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, probably using the OR operator for relationship matching, i.e. `()-[r:FIRST_WAY|SECOND_WAY]->()`, and then examining the patterns matched to discard some of the result paths based on the relationship type.

Comment: I will accept this answer, as coalesce does it for Cypher 1.9